# What should I do after user registration with React Redux?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-router, react-redux

I am using React Js + Redux + React Router.

1. What is the best practice with user login/register flow?.
2. How many reducers do I need for that: one or two (one for login and one for registration)?
3. What should I do after user register? Should I redirect to login or redirect to the home page and make user authenticated? If so, it is mean that I need one reducer for login and register, because I need to store auth user in one place?

For now, I suppose for 2 reducers (login and register) and 6 actions:

```
export const LOGIN_REQUEST = 'login_request';
export const LOGIN_SUCCESS = 'login_success';
export const LOGIN_FAILURE = 'login_failure';

export const REGISTER_REQUEST = 'register_request';
export const REGISTER_SUCCESS = 'register_success';
export const REGISTER_FAILURE = 'register_failure';
```

But what is better to implement?

Answer (score 1):

That's the interesting part in React, you can write it in so many ways to accomplish the same thing.

As for as the implementation is concerned it all depends on your use case. But on your requirement, I personally, like to use 3 reducers.

1. Login Reducer - this will return the state consisting of login information of user along with auth token(that will be used on each request) on successful action.
2. Register Reducer - this will have all the user related information that he gave us during the registration process (it will persist till the page refreshes).
3. Users Reducer - I suppose this is the reducer which will be used frequently. It can be used to return the state of users when listing, editing, adding & deleting.

After login, its always better to take the user to home page and cut down that extra step for him to login again after successful registration. But then you might need to show up message to verify his/her email address as a secondary measure.

Well, this is all my personal opinion and you are free to choose how you want to code.

That's it man!

Happy coding:)